# How can I send telegram message using asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram

I wrote an asp code couple with c# to send a message to a mobile number. I have a valid api_id and api_hash. The program works well in C# windows form application. However, I encountered a new error on ASP.net with C# on `bool isConnected = await telegram.ConnectAsync();`.

The error message is:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.ZLib, Version=2.0.0.14, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve such error?

**ASP.Net:**

```
    %@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Mobile Number"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Message"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using TLSharp.Core;
using TeleSharp.TL;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Alert="";
        string phoneNumber = "*********";
        int api_id = ******; string api_hash = "********************";
        var store = new FileSessionStore();
        TLUser user = null;
        var client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash, store);
        bool isConnected = await client.ConnectAsync();
        if (!isConnected)
            Alert = "Check wifi connection!";
        while (!client.IsUserAuthorized())
        {
            var phoneCodeHash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(phoneNumber);
            Alert = "Input verification code on your phone here:";
            var code = "*****"; // you can change code in debugger, code will send via telegram to you
            user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(phoneNumber, phoneCodeHash, code);
        }
        string[] phonelist = new string[2];

        if (client.IsUserAuthorized())
        {
            //get available contacts
            var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();

            //find recipient in contacts
            var userr = result.users.lists.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser)).Cast<TLUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.phone == "98"+TextBox1.Text);

            //send message
            await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = userr.id }, TextBox2.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the error message? `Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.ZLib, `. The code doesn't matter at all if you are missing a required library. *Have* you installed all dependencies? Where does the error occur?

Comment: The error msg is simple...You are missing some DLL or File

Comment: Does the error occur in your development machine or on the production server? Did you forget to copy all required dlls when deploying the site? Where does `TelegramClient` come from? Downloaded library? NuGet package? Perhaps there's a missing dependency on the package?

Comment: I suspect the method FileSessionStore() need a filename and is the filename is missing or invalid.  The Error message is against the Net System.IO library.

Comment: @jdweng no it isn't. It's about a missing assembly, not a missing file. `Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.ZLib`

Comment: If it was an assembly then the code wouldn't compile.  It sound like to me a configuration file missing.

Comment: I am running the project on a development machine which is not a server. I have loaded Telesharp.TL.dll and TLSharp.Core.dll as I loaded in code of C# windows form application. However, asp code does not work, while windows form application code works well.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net web pages and code files are compiled dynamically when the user first request a resource.

So, in your code you reference a third-party assembly.  Everything in the IDE will validate correctly.  But in actually use, the third-party assembly reference another assembly. In this case, the Ionic.ZLib assembly.

The easiest way to add the missing assembly is to use [Ionic.Zlib Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ionic.Zlib/).

```
Package Manager
PM>  Install-Package Ionic.Zlib -Version 1.9.1.5
```

```
>  dotnet add package Ionic.Zlib --version 1.9.1.5
```